# How to convert batch script to registry context menu file REG_MULTI_SZ

Tags: batch-file, registry, batch-processing

I want to convert a multi-line batch script to a `REG_MULTI_SZ` command.

I want to use it as a context menu item in file explorer to kill all tasks not responding .

I can get this to work with the following registry entry command.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\KillNotResponding]
"MUIverb"="Kill Tasks Not Responding"
"Position"="Bottom"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,-240"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\KillNotResponding\command]
@="cmd /k taskkill /f /fi \"Status EQ Not Responding\" && timeout /t 2 && exit"
```

I am trying to do this because it is easier to write a multiline batch file than put everything on a single line `REG_SZ`.

I am trying to use the following batch script as a `REG_MULTI_SZ`.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set prompt=$S$H
:: Kill all tasks not responding ::
cecho {0A} &
start cmd /k taskkill /f /fi \"status EQ Not Responding\" &
timeout /t 2 nul &
endlocal
exit /b
```

I am aware that REG_MULTI_SZ only uses HEX(7).

Here is the above batch script convereted to HEX (7)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\KillNotResponding]
@="Kill Tasks Not Responding"
"Position"="Bottom"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,-240"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\KillNotResponding\command]
"Kill Tasks Not Responding"=hex(7):40,00,65,00,63,00,68,00,6F,00,20,00,6F,00,\
       66,00,66,00,00,00,69,00,66,00,20,00,2F,00,69,00,20,00,6E,00,6F,00,74,00,\
     20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,3D,00,3D,00,20,00,22,00,6D,00,61,00,\
     78,00,22,00,20,00,73,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,2F,00,6D,00,61,00,\
     78,00,20,00,63,00,6D,00,64,00,20,00,2F,00,63,00,20,00,25,00,30,00,20,00,\
     6D,00,61,00,78,00,20,00,26,00,20,00,65,00,78,00,69,00,74,00,20,00,2F,00,\
     62,00,00,00,73,00,65,00,74,00,6C,00,6F,00,63,00,61,00,6C,00,00,00,00,00,\
     73,00,65,00,74,00,20,00,70,00,72,00,6F,00,6D,00,70,00,74,00,3D,00,24,00,\
       53,00,24,00,48,00,00,00,00,00,3A,00,3A,00,20,00,4B,00,69,00,6C,00,6C,00,\
     20,00,61,00,6C,00,6C,00,20,00,74,00,61,00,73,00,6B,00,73,00,20,00,6E,00,\
         6F,00,74,00,20,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,70,00,6F,00,6E,00,64,00,69,00,6E,00,\
         67,00,20,00,3A,00,3A,00,00,00,63,00,65,00,63,00,68,00,6F,00,20,00,7B,00,\
     30,00,41,00,7D,00,20,00,26,00,00,00,73,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,\
         63,00,6D,00,64,00,20,00,2F,00,6B,00,20,00,74,00,61,00,73,00,6B,00,6B,00,\
         69,00,6C,00,6C,00,20,00,2F,00,66,00,20,00,2F,00,66,00,69,00,20,00,5C,00,\
         22,00,73,00,74,00,61,00,74,00,75,00,73,00,20,00,45,00,51,00,20,00,4E,00,\
         6F,00,74,00,20,00,52,00,65,00,73,00,70,00,6F,00,6E,00,64,00,69,00,6E,00,\
         67,00,5C,00,22,00,20,00,26,00,00,00,74,00,69,00,6D,00,65,00,6F,00,75,00,\
         74,00,20,00,2F,00,74,00,20,00,32,00,20,00,26,00,00,00,00,00,65,00,6E,00,\
         64,00,6C,00,6F,00,63,00,61,00,6C,00,00,00,65,00,78,00,69,00,74,00,20,00,\
         2F,00,62,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, is it your understanding, intention, or both, to have each line of a batch file as the content of the multi string value, but with the separators taking the place of the batch files line breaks? If it is, and you're expecting it to run like a batch file, I would expect that you'd have more success spitting into the wind.

Comment: Thanks. Helpful.

Comment: Okay then…would you prefer, **it is not possible**?

Comment: Yes. That is a better way to help me understand why my attempts failed.